# Interior or exterior paint for unconditioned three-season room?

Tags: painting, sunroom

My husband and I are looking to paint the ceiling of our sunroom. We live in an area that gets really hot and humid in the summer and bitterly cold in the winter.

This space is enclosed, but the 3 walls that face externally all have windows and a slider door to the backyard, so there will be added moisture to this space for sure, and no ventilation vents from the main house.

We have been dithering back and forth as what to get, as other forums that have similar questions all state that generally 'it depends'

Any advice and help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: When people say "it's really humid out today," they're actually describing a high dew point. As the dew point approaches 98.6 degrees (body temp), your sweat has a harder time evaporating. Florida, intuitively, is the second most humid US state. The most humid US state, counterintuitively, is Alaska.

Comment: What material is the ceiling surface?

Answer (score 2):

Bathroom paint could be the way to go, it's hard-wearing against humidity.
Most paints survive well (indoors) against the cold.

The only downside you may need to consider is that there might not be as many paint colour options available.
And it may be more expensive that regular paint

Comment: More expensive. But colors? Any paint store (from a hardware store to a big box to a paint-only store) can mix just about any type of paint in hundreds of different colors.

Answer (score 1):

Three-season (unconditioned) "porch" or sunroom additions are common in my area, where we have similar climate. My home has such a room, and it's well below zero F in winter and as hot as 100° F in summer with dew points in the 70s. Interior acrylic latex paint does just fine.